# How can I get the JSON string from a URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, url

I'm trying to get the data from a URL that returns data in a JSON string.

URL: http://forums.zybez.net/pages/2007-price-guide-api?term=adamant+axe

What I want to do is store this string in a variable like so: 
var jsonData = '[get JSON string from URL]';

But I'm not sure how to get the JSON string from the URL.
Any help would be appreciated!! :-)

Comment: Use `$.getJSON` or JSONP if this is cross domain. I'm betting this is cross domain, so you will need to use JSONP, but the server will have to be able to accommodate JSONP

Comment: The service does'nt seem to be supporting CORS or JSONP, so the short answer is; You can't get that data from the clientside, you'll need a serverside script you can call.

Comment: If you want to do this from inside your own JavaScript code on your own site, you cannot.  Browsers won't let you fetch content from a URL with a different domain.

Comment: $.getJSON returns a "jqXHR," how do I convert this into a string?

Comment: @user1464011 you can't do this at all from your own site.  It would only work if your site is "forums.zybez.net".

Comment: I've already tested this, and it returns "is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin", if you'd like to convert that error message to a string, that should'nt be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

The `jQuery.getJSON()` functions gives you easy access to JSON data returned from server. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: That'll work from something like the browser JavaScript console, but not from JavaScript code on a site with a different domain.

Answer (score 0):

This is an X-Domain-Request you're trying to do.
By default this is forbidden - for security reasons.

You could either implement a JSONP callback.
You would then send the name of a callback (that'd have to be generated on every request) to the server you'd like to receive data from and in return this server would provide you with a function you could call up to retrieve your data from.

The other option would be a CORs server 
http://enable-cors.org/server.html the HTTP-Server you're requesting data has to have a software module processing you're request appropriately, sending the correct MIME-type and so forth.

Still, there is another way:
use a "wrapper"

You could set up a web server that works in-between.
It would download your request and forward it to you.
Just like if you would request the data directly from this server (obviously you do, but it's not the actual server providing the data).

One way of implementing this would be to use a PHP script to download the data and direct it to you.

the basic parts of a sample implementation:

- your **html** file requesting data:
  **processData.html** (requesting data from 127.0.0.1/**getData.php**? **location** =**URL**)
- your **php** file serving as a wrapper and downloading data from **URL** (where location is your parameter you're sending to the wrapper file):
  getData.php
- where your actual server is at (**URL**) provided to the php file as a parameter **location**
  (make sure to escape the URL parameter before sending it to your php file)

there are much more ways of implementing what you're trying to achieve.

best of luck!